# Bypassing of the filepath for creating thumbnails for images in s3 bucket simultaneously

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My `requirement` is to create three images of different sizes simultaneously on a `S3 bucket`. I found a node module namely [node-s3-uploader](https://github.com/Turistforeningen/node-s3-uploader) which suits my requirement. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/Turistforeningen/node-s3-uploader), if I want to upload an image, I need to provide the `image path`. But I am uploading a file not from my local disk but I am posting it through `Advanced Rest Client` a Chrome Plugin. Can somebody Suggest me how can bypass the image path description for the `node-s3-uploader`?

If it is not possible, is their another mechanism that I need to follow?

Comment: How do you normally reference the uploaded image when it is uploaded through the `Advanced Rest Client`?

Comment: I reference it as muitipart form data when I send a image to my API using `Advanced Rest Client`.